# ReactJS Loop through object not returning values

Tags: javascript

I have:

```
let contactData = {};
        if (this.props.enquiry.contact) {
            contactData.name = this.props.enquiry.contact.firstName + ' ' + this.props.enquiry.contact.lastName;
        }
```

And then:

```
Object.keys(this.props.data).map((line, idx) => {
            console.log(line)
        });
```

But the output is the key (name) and not the value. How do I get the value of the name parameter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this

```
Object.keys(this.props.data).map((line, idx) => {
  console.log(this.props.data[line]); // get value from Object by key
});
```

> [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) method returns an array of a given object's own
>   enumerable properties

Example

```js
var obj = { a: 1, b: 2 };

// Object.keys(obj) returns ['a', 'b'];
var res = Object.keys(obj).map((key) => {
  // in order to get value from Object by key we can use bracket notation
  return obj[key];
});

console.log(res);
```